# Change number of posts on consecutive category pages (Wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress-theming, wordpress

I am trying change the number of posts that are displayed on a category pages to change on consecutive pages (page 2, 3, etc). So page one displays 7 posts, but pages 2, 3 and 4, etc of that category display only 6 posts per page (i.e. when you click 'next page' to list the older posts).

I am aware that it is relatively straightforward to change the number of posts for different categories / archive pages - but this is different, as I would like the paginated pages to have different numbers of posts.

Any ideas?

Comment: You could use the `paged` parameter to change the number of posts, you could have some problems with the pagination, pay attention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is from an answer I recently done on WPSE. I have made some changes to suite your needs. You can go and check out that post [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/155782/31545)

**STEP 1**

If you have changed the main query for a custom query, change it back to the default loop

```
<?php

        if ( have_posts() ) :
            // Start the Loop.
            while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

                ///<---YOUR LOOP--->

            endwhile;

                //<---YOUR PAGINATION--->   

            else : 

                //NO POSTS FOUND OR SOMETHING   

            endif; 

    ?>
```

**STEP 2**

Use `pre_get_posts` to alter the main query to change the `posts_per_page` parameter on the category pages

**STEP 3**

Now, get the `posts_per_page` option set from the back end (which I assume is 6) and also set your `offset` which we are going to use. That will be `1` as you will need 7 posts on page one and 6 on the rest

```
$ppg = get_option('posts_per_page');
$offset = 1;
```

**STEP 4**

On page one, you'll need to add the `offset` to `posts_per_page` will add up to 7 to get your seven posts on page one.

```
$query->set('posts_per_page', $offset + $ppp);
```

**STEP 5**

You must apply your `offset` to all subsequent pages, otherwise you will get a repetition of the last post of the page on the next page

```
$offset = $offset + ( ($query->query_vars['paged']-1) * $ppp );
$query->set('posts_per_page',$ppp);
$query->set('offset',$offset);
```

**STEP 6**

Lastly, you need to subtract your offset from `found_posts` otherwise your pagination on the last page will be wrong and give you a `404` error as the last post will be missing due to the incorrect post count

```
function category_offset_pagination( $found_posts, $query ) {
    $offset = 1;

    if( !is_admin() && $query->is_category() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $found_posts = $found_posts - $offset;
    }
    return $found_posts;
}
add_filter( 'found_posts', 'category_offset_pagination', 10, 2 );
```

**ALL TOGETHER**

This is how your complete query will look like that should go into functions.php

```
function ppp_and_offset_category_page( $query ) {
  if ($query->is_category() && $query->is_main_query() && !is_admin()) {
    $ppp = get_option('posts_per_page');
    $offset = 1;
    if (!$query->is_paged()) {
      $query->set('posts_per_page',$offset + $ppp);
    } else {
      $offset = $offset + ( ($query->query_vars['paged']-1) * $ppp );
      $query->set('posts_per_page',$ppp);
      $query->set('offset',$offset);
    }
  }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts','ppp_and_offset_category_page');

function category_offset_pagination( $found_posts, $query ) {
    $offset = 1;

    if( !is_admin() && $query->is_category() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $found_posts = $found_posts - $offset;
    }
    return $found_posts;
}
add_filter( 'found_posts', 'category_offset_pagination', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: I'm trying but have yet to have any joy by inputting the code as described. I have one difference to the loop as described above: the pagination  <div id="page-nav"  ><?php next_posts_link() ?></div> has been placed after the loop '?>' as I need to have the navigation controls in a separate div.

Comment: Anything specific you are struggeling with that I can assist you with. On which page/template are you trying to do this

Comment: I'm using twentyfourteen (modified for my own purposes) on category.php

Comment: In my last block of code I made an copy and paste error, `is_home()` should be `is_category()`. I've corrected it

Comment: Ok, thanks. I've added category.php to pastbin in case [link](http://pastebin.com/q0zdrU3b).

Comment: Seems to be working, but displaying 8 posts on page one and 7 on consecutive!?! (unable to commence chat - insufficient reputation)

Comment: Ok, this means that you have your posts per page in reading setting set to 7 and not 6 if my mind serves me right

Comment: Very true - all fixed now! Thanks so much :) Great help - hugely appreciated.

Comment: My pleasure. Glad I could help. Enjoy :-)

Comment: The solution works like a dream *but* in search results (search.php), the next_post_link does not display. I have found this: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/77661/next-posts-link-works-only-with-original-wp-query , which hints at the problem, although I can't quite understand how I can modify the code you have made to rectify the search.php issue.

Comment: For search pge, you have to change all instances of `is_category()` to `is_search()`

Comment: Oh, I see - thanks. I copied and duplicated all the code, replacing 'category_offset_pagination' for 'search_offset_pagination' and 'function ppp_and_offset_category_page' for 'function ppp_and_offset_search_page' along with is_category for is_search

Comment: The next_posts_link doesn't display, however. For search.php, All pages can have the same number of posts on each page (there is no need for 8 then 7).

Comment: Please start a [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) as this is an unrelated issue :-)

Comment: Happily, but it seems this code is causing the problem...?

Comment: Quite strange, will test it and see what I come up with

Comment: Just test again without the second block of code where the offset is set. I suspect that piece of code.

Comment: Great - that seems to have fixed it! :) Is this part of code not needed then?

Comment: That is needed. If this is ommitted, the last page will 404. Will see how I can correct the function

Comment: Sorted, see my updated code. It should work fine now

Comment: It was my pleasure. I must say thanks to you. Because of this issue  you've raised I had a new look and actually updated my original code on WPSE as well, so you have actually helped other future users as well. Enjoy your festive season. :-)